# Marcus Number Fields chapter 5 exercise 8

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, principal-ideal-domains

The exercise is the following: one should show that $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{223}]$ has ideal class group which is a cyclic group of order $3$.

I tried to follow the standard path which Marcus uses to determine other ideal class groups: firstly, I calculated $\lambda$ which turns out to be $\sqrt{223}$. Having that, one reduces to check what happens to prime in $R$ which are above $2,3,5,7,11,13$.

I've checked that the prime above $2,5,7,11,13$ are trivial in the ideal class group and using Kummer theorem I've found that $$3R=(3,1+\sqrt{223})(3,1-\sqrt{223}) .$$

Let's call this two primes respectively $p,q$. One can check that $14-\sqrt{223} \in p $ and $14-\sqrt{223} \not \in q$, while the nrm of this element is $-27$, so that one got $p^3=(14-\sqrt{223})=e$ in the ideal class group. With a similar reasoning, one got $q^3=e$ in the ideal class group.

Now, if we manage to demonstrate that $p,q$ are not principal we are done. If one of this ideal were principal, the element which generates it should have norm $\pm 3$. So , we are reduced to show the following :there are no solutions in $\mathbb{Z}$ of $a^2-223b^2=\pm3$.

The one with the $+$ is showed to be impossible using reciprocity, while I've got no idea to end for the other equation.

Comment: It suffices to find a unit $u>1$ because then there must be a solution $c\in \pm(1,u)$ whose conjugate is $\pm 3/c$ giving a bound on the coefficients of its minimal polynomial

Comment: See Theorem 3.3 and worked examples in sections 4 and 5 at https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ugradnumthy/pelleqn2.pdf.